# Is this derivative of $\ln x$ correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is this derivative of lnx correct?

Thanks in advance :)

$$y = \ln x \\
x = e^y \\
\frac{d}{dx} x = \frac{d}{dx} e^y \\
1 = \frac{d}{dx} e^y \\ \\
1 = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dy} e^y \\ \\
1 = \frac{d}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} e^y \\ \\
\frac{1}{e^y} = \frac{dy}{dx} \\ \\
 = \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is given by
$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$
assumed $f'(a)$ exists and does not equal zero. Let $f(x)=e^{x}$, then $f^{-1}(x)=\ln(x)$, thus
$$\ln'(x)=\frac{1}{(e^{x})'|_{\ln(x)}}=\frac{1}{e^{\ln x}}=\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 2):

A lot of steps, maybe too many.

Let $y= \ln x$. Then $x=e^y$, hence
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{dy}{dx}e^y \\
\implies \frac{1}{e^y} &= \frac{dy}{dx} \\
\ldots
\end{align}

Comment: Maybe I'm alone in this, but I find it "clearer" to write $\ e^ {y} \ \frac{dy}{dx} \ $ or $\ \frac{dy}{dx} \ . \ \ e^ {y} $ than $\frac{dy}{dx} \ e^ {y} $